# Should there be a jurisdiction tag for the District of Columbia?

Tags: discussion, tags

The District of Columbia (DC), USA,  is governed by the US federal government, but it also has a local government with significant autonomy.

Should we have a [district-of-columbia](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/district-of-columbia) tag for questions about the District's local laws?  Or is this more properly a subset of [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)?

Answer (score 5):

### Tags are free

If you think a question needs a [district-of-columbia](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/district-of-columbia) tag then you go ahead and add it. Tags exist to make searching easier and more tags are better than fewer tags.

There is space for 5 tags on a question - only 1,065 out of 16,095 questions currently (12 June 2020) use all 5 (6.6%). Adding a relevant tag where there is space is always a good idea. Replacing a tag with a more relevant tag is probably a good idea - consider if the tag you are proposing to add will help more people find the question than the tag you are proposing to remove will.

However, be aware that editing a question bumps it to the top of the active queue, if you are going to change several questions, please spread the edits out over time so the front page doesn’t get swamped with them.

Comment: Well, if there's agreement that one is warranted then there are a number of questions that I could retag accordingly.  But if it's a bad idea for some reason and someone is going to go back and delete all my tags, I'd rather know before I start.

Comment: @NateEldredge see edits.

Comment: If you're going to do it, please don't go through and do all of them at once. A handful a day, at most, to avoid drowning new questions with bumps for minor change. @NateEldredge

Comment: Alternate tag/Synonym: [tag:Washington-DC]